# Using VBA to open Password Protected Files

Tags: excel, vba

Hi very new to VBA and coding so all help would be very appreciated.

So i have about 37 files which i need to open with VBA and then take some data and aggregate it into a summary however some of the files are password protected thankfully with the same password.

I am using the Application.Get Open file name to get the location of all the files and then usings a loop from 1 to n to open the `FileNames(i)` what can i do so that as the workbook is opened and it asks for the password it types in the password "password1".

I have tried `ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="Password"` however does not seem to work as the work book needs to be opened before this will unprotect it.

```
Sub Aggregation_Data()
Dim FileNames As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim TWB As Workbook, aWB As Workbook



Set TWB = ThisWorkbook

MsgBox ("Enter Files that you wish to import data from")

FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Filter (*.xlsx), *xlsx", Title:="Open File(s)", MultiSelect:=True)

For i = 1 To UBound(FileNames)

Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="Password"


Next i

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFm0J.png)

Comment: [`Workbooks.Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) has a *Password* parameter.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/using-vba-to-open-password-protected-files.1133892/. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

In your For loop, try:

Workbooks.Open (FileNames(i), Password:="Password")

Answer (score 0):

`.Protect` and `.Unprotect` are refers to the function of avoiding from user amends the script. For workbook password, you may use the `Workbook.open` parameter as mentioned above.

Comment: Hi I have tried that but get a complie error "Expected ="

Answer (score 0):

So i found the answer thought would share it turns out just having the comma in the right place.

Set TWB = ThisWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Filter (*.xlsx), *xlsx", Title:="Open File(s)", MultiSelect:=True)

For i = 1 To UBound(FileNames)
Workbooks.Open FileNames(i), Password:="Password"
Next i